# How do I limit the amount of pages showing up in my wordpress to speed up my site?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce

Hi I recently started a shopping search engine and we are hitting the 50k product mark and rising. My issue is that when there are too many pages loaded in my WordPress the site starts to slow dramatically. I have tried caching and several stack methods however they do not work as we have updates that are done daily and it would not make sense to cache or try these other methods.

Anyway I found this code on stack it seems like it could do what I need it to do but I do not know how to implement it. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to add this to our woocommerce site. Where it would go.? I need a php for dummys guide right about now.

```
    public function paginateCount($conditions = null,
                             $recursive = 0,
                             $extra = array()) {
       return 1000;
    }
```

My site is http://cartgrabber.com/shop/ as you can see it takes about 20 seconds to load this page but pages with less pages in the pagination it only takes a few seconds.

Again I don't necessarily need to call my items as long as they are searchable and we can have filters in place to narrow down products we should be fine with this.

Comment: can you add your index.php codes to your question ?

Comment: Are you using wp_query's built in pagination? It sounds like the pagination you're using might not be set up correctly...

Comment: I'm using the woocommerce default pagination. This is what they currently have for code.

Comment: echo paginate_links(apply_filters('woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
        'base' => esc_url_raw(str_replace(999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg('add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link(999999999, false)))),
        'format' => '',
        'add_args' => '',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => '<div class="page-separator-prev">&laquo;</div>',
        'next_text' => '<div class="page-separator-next">&raquo;</div>',
        'type' => 'list',
        'end_size' => 3,
        'mid_size' => 3
    )));

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with the Aspire theme on a project and by default it isn't slow, it's just that your Database query is taking up too much time leading to a very high TTFB.

[Page load time analysis >>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe1IQ.png)

What you can do is reduce the number of queries (one way to do so is reduce the number of Products displayed and menu items as you are asking) or If you have control over your server implement Memcached. It wouldn't be bad to implement ONLY object caching using a plugin, as that would not hinder updates and other changes. You can turn Static Cache and Minify off.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I will try the object caching option. Do you suggest any easy to use cache plugins?

Comment: If you are willing to pay, WP Rocket is amazing. If not, W3 Total does the same job but its a little heavier and bloaty. Be sure to enable just object caching. 

While you are at it, also consider compressing images. It won't make a big difference especially on fast connections but will definately make some.